# Microarray experiment validation meaning

Tags: genetics, gene, data, experiment, microarray

I have a quick question: what does microarray experiment validation mean ?

I was reading a paper in which they say that the data of the experiment show that the 3 genes *radB, dp1 and dp2* are co-regulated following gamma irradiation "validating our microarray experiment".

I tried to find something in Google but it is not yet clear.

Comment: I think here it means the results of their gamma irradiation experiment give the same results as the microarray experiment.  Here 'validating' means 'support'.

Comment: ok thank you @user438383